# Arel `between` with other columns as range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

It seems that Arel's `Between` predicate can be used with ranges only, eg

```
between(1.day.ago.time..Time.current)
```

Does anyone know a way to use it with other columns? Like

```
between(table[:since]..table[:till])
```

(the last will not work but it shows an idea).
In the end I want

```
column BETWEEN table.since AND table.till
```

Comment: You can always use `find_by_sql`

Answer (score 2):

To generate `table.field BETWEEN another_table.from AND another_table.to` use this arel code:

```
Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
  table[:field],
  Arel::Nodes::And.new(
    [
      another_table[:from],
      another_table[:to]
    ]
  )
)
```

In my case I placed this code into `.and()` arel method.